# How to count the total lines of a rich text

Tags: javascript

I got a string edited by rich text, now I need to show, and when it more than three lines, I need to hide the rest. But I do not know how to get the total lines of the rich text. Since it has all kinds of labels like p, h1, h1, span...
Maybe you get a string like follow:

```
Titledescription description description description description description description description description description description description description description description descriptiondescription description description description description description description description description description description description...and some others order list
and some others order list
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an example of your rich text?

Comment: Also I believe you mean a Rich Text File `.rtf`.

Comment: I gave a possible example, It was edited by a Rich Text, now I want to count the lines of the string.

Comment: raw text of your rich text please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really count the lines as you have no idea what the user input may be vs the screen size of the output. a `<H1>` will take a lot more vertical space than a `<P>` The user may the browser text zoomed in or out as well.

You'd be better off with some css.

```
 .limit-text-2-rows {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    line-height: 21px;
    max-height: 48px;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confinced it's possible, but it's tricky.
Somewhere in 2013 I wrote two functions to count the lines within an inline element (any inline, so also inline-block) and one function (quite hacky but useable) to apply ellipsis to an HTML element.

The function to count lines is quite short:
(dug up from an old code repository my boss put online: https://github.com/WebHare/designfiles/blob/master/wh.layout.measure/wh.layout.measure.js )

```
/** @short count the amount of lines within an inline element
*/
$wh.countLinesInElement = function countLinesInElement(node)
{
  var rects = node.getClientRects();

  // Firefox returns a rects for each line,
  // Chrome can return multiple rects per line
  var lines = 0;
  for (var idx = 0; idx < rects.length; idx++)
  {
    if (idx == 0 || rects[idx-1].top != rects[idx].top)
      lines ++;
  }
  return lines;
}
```

Caveats/issues:

- it only counts lines within inline elements (I also have a version which used the rects from ranges, I don't remember whether that one worked on non-inline elements).
- not tested at all on flexbox, multicolumn or grid layouts (they were not ready for use on live sites in 2013)
- Chrome returned multiple rects per line, so I guess (not tested) this means some CSS properties may affect the top and confuse this simple function

This method might be useable to find to which element you need to apply ellipsis.  You would need to iterate through the elements (and subchildren if they are block elements). When you find the element which would overflow you could apply -webkit-line-clamps (which weirdly enough all browsers except IE support nowadays).
Ofcourse this all is somewhat hacky so whether it's possible and worth it depends on what you want to use it for.

The other function I mentioned I made to apply multiline ellipsis to richtext just used the bounding client rects and tried to shorten the text until it fit within the specified maximum space. Not so performance friendly, it needed to do it reflow-intensive way of applying ellipsis every time when the document was resized. (also it used MooTools, but that would be used to change to plain Javascript) It's here if you want to see:

https://github.com/WebHare/designfiles/blob/master/wh.layout.applyellipsishtml/wh.layout.applyellipsishtml.js